# Magento 2 CSV bulk upload product for multi website with a different price

Tags: magento2, price, csv, multi-website

Need to upload CSV for multi website e.g "`base,us`"

`base` will have £100.00

`us` will have  $110.00

I have a sample where I change price from admin But when I export CSV I only see the price for the base where is the `us` price ?
Need help to understand how to do this if is possible.

Tahnk you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a Solution.

So first upload product to `default` *store view* and `base` *website*

In the CSV file add in the column `store_view_code` e.g = `default` and in `product_websites` column e.g = `base` and Import. So once this is imported successfully then export it and change the following columns again.

`store_view_code` e.g = `en_us` and `product_websites` column e.g = `us` and of course the column `price` and import again. that's it.

Comment: There is no method to do this in 1 go? Maybe a core code update?